# Auto complete in gridview textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I have a gridview in which there is textbox now I want to apply autocomplete in that textbox
    enter code here

```
                 alert('hi gridview');
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("*[id$=gvProduct] input[type=text][id*=txtProdType]").autocomplete({

                         source: function (request, response) {
                             $.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 url: "/Tally/SaleTest.aspx/autocompleteProdType",
                                 data: "{'searchText':'" + document.getElementById('txtProdType').value + "'}",

                                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                 dataType: "json",

                                 success: function (data) {
                                     response(data.d);
                                 },


                                 error: function (result) {

                                 }
                             });
                         },
                         autoFocus: true,
                         minLength: 1,
                         open: function (event, ui) {
                             $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', '99999');
                         },


                         select: function (event, selectedObject) {
                             jQuery(this).val(selectedObject.item.value);
                         }

                     });

                 });

                </script>
```

how to solve it

I have a gridview in which there is textbox now I want to apply autocomplete in that textbox

Comment: I am using jquery so I can not see error

Comment: Open console in your browser and check for errors.

Comment: do you get text in `data.d`?

Comment: Try this$('#<%=gvProduct.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtProdType"]');

Comment: I alredy mention in gridview and textbox clientID  static